# C preprocessor on Mac OSX/iPhone, usage of the '#' key?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, c-preprocessor, stringification

I'm looking at some open source projects and I'm seeing the following:

```
NSLog(@"%s w=%f, h=%f", #size, size.width, size.height)
```

What exactly is the meaning of '#' right before the size symbol? Is that some kind of prefix for **C** strings?

Comment: Curious... you wouldn't happen to have the name of the actual project handy, and location of this code, would you? There must be something else going on, as dirkgently suggests, because this doesn't even compile for me.

Comment: It's actually from Joe Hewitt's Three20 project. The define looks like this:

#define TTLOGRECT(rect) \
  TTLOG(@"%s x=%f, y=%f, w=%f, h=%f", #rect, rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y, \
    rect.size.width, rect.size.height)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The official name of `#` is the *stringizing operator*.  It takes its argument and surrounds it in quotes to make a C string constant, escaping any embedded quotes or backslashes as necessary.  It is only allowed inside the definition of a macro -- it is not allowed in regular code.  For example:

```
// This is not legal C
const char *str = #test

// This is ok
#define STRINGIZE(x) #x
const char *str1 = STRINGIZE(test);      // equivalent to str1 = "test";
const char *str2 = STRINGIZE(test2"a\"");  // equivalent to str2 = "test2\"a\\\"";
```

A related preprocessor operator is the *token-pasting operator* `##`.  It takes two tokens and pastes them together to get one token.  Like the stringizing operator, it is only allowed in macro definitions, not in regular code.

```
// This is not legal C
int foobar = 3;
int x = foo ## bar;

// This is ok
#define TOKENPASTE(x, y) x ## y
int foobar = 3;
int x = TOKENPASTE(foo, bar);  // equivalent to x = foobar;
```

Answer (score 8):

To elaborate on dirkgently's answer, this looks like the implementation of a macro that takes an NSSize (or similar) argument, and prints the name of the variable (which is what the # is doing; converting the name of the variable to a string containing the name of the variable) and then its values. So in:

```
NSSize fooSize = NSMakeSize(2, 3);
MACRO_NAME_HERE(fooSize);
```

the macro would expand to:

```
NSLog(@"%s w=%f h=%f", "fooSize", fooSize.width, fooSize.height);
```

and print:

```
fooSize w=2.0 h=3.0
```

(similar to NSStringFromSize, but with the variable name)

Answer (score 4):

Is this the body of a macro definition? Then the `#` could be used to stringize the following identifier i.e. to print "string" (without the codes).